# PayPal Express Checkout returns to CANCELURL after a successful payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

So I'm working with Express Checkout and everything seems to be going well. I noticed a strange thing though, in about 1 out of 1000 payments, the routine is the following:

- All good during SetExpressCheckoutPayment, sending to PayPal
- PayPal processes the payment, returns the user to to my RETURNURL
- I charge the user with DoExpressCheckoutPayment and get the success response, yey!
- A few seconds later PayPal sends me an IPN with a successful payment, cool!
- Around 30 seconds later, my CANCELURL gets hit with that same token

Now that's confusing. Checking the transaction with GetTransactionDetails says Completed, but my user's purchase is set to Cancelled. One way would be to simply ignore a CANCELURL hit on successful transactions, but I'd really like to know why is this happening.

Have you ever noticed the same thing happening on your site? Any idea what the user workflow might be to generate such a glitch? Any other workaround ideas except ignoring calls to CANCELURL after a successful payment?

Thanks all!

Comment: Not sure, but one guess to test -- submit a payment, while it is processing, try canceling it. I *think* the `CANCELURL` is only triggered via the Cancel Link. Even further, contact the customer to confirm their purchase as well.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I tried doing that in my sandbox environment but the Cancel link does nothing as soon as the Pay Now button is clicked. The whole thing just fades out. I also thought of opening two payments in two tabs, paying one and closing the other, but the tokens are different, so they're treated as two different payments. Will need to test in production I guess.

Comment: Thats what I suspected. Your most efficient method may be to contact the customer. The benefit is two-fold, ensuring they intended to pay for the item, and find out what steps they took to pay for the item.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed sometimes the mini browser is not faded when you click on "pay now" button (see [Express Checkout for Digital Goods : can click several times on Pay now button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437403/express-checkout-for-digital-goods-can-click-several-times-on-pay-now-button)).

So maybe your users click on pay, nothing seems to happen for them so they click on cancel link.
I'm looking for a way to prevent this (clicking on "cancel" or twice on "pay now"), if you know how...