# Express Checkout for Digital Goods : can click several times on Pay now button

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

**Problem :**
Paypal opens a lightbox when you want to buy something with Express Checkout Digital Goods.
On this lightbox you can click several times on "Pay now" button, this is bad user experience and it breaks my backend scripts.

**Steps :**

1. I integrate Express Checkout for Digital goods in my Flash website. I use the Paypal script "https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js", and to open Paypal lightbox I do :

   ```
   dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow();
   dg.startFlow(setup_url);
   ```

   Then my website is under a mask, and a lightbox appears.

   The setup_url is the url of my php script that sets up the Paypal transaction. When the setup is ok, it redirects to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=...&useraction=commit
2. I am not remembered by Paypal, the lightbox shows a button "Log in", I click on it.
3. A popup appears over the lightbox, to log in. I check the "Remember me" checkbox and log in.
4. The popup displays the cart, I click on "Pay now" button.
5. IMMEDIATELY the popup closes, and the lightbox displays "loading" while the script I set as "return_url" is executing.
6. I start the Paypal DGFlow again, but now I am remembered.
7. The lightbox appears and shows the cart (there is no adding popup), I click on "Pay now"
8. Nothing seems to happen !! Actually, the script I set as "return_url" is executing, but the Paypal lightbox does not show the "loading" message and just stay on the cart. I can click again and again on "Pay now", and each time I click on this button, Paypal calls return_url.

**Question :**
Is it a bug ?
Do you see the same behaviour ?
Do you know a workaround to prevent the user to click several times on the "Pay now" button ?

Comment: Just spitballing here because I dont use flash, but if you put the JS under a flash cover, doesn't that prevent the webbrowser from accessing the button object and disabling it after click to prevent multiple clicks?

Comment: The flash is integrated in an html page with swfobject.js. The paypal dg.js displays the Express Checkout interface in another iframe, on top of my html page, if I understand well. I can interact with the paypal interface since I can login and pay. I don't know why the JS could not access the button object to disable it after the click.